# Data isn't being refreshed when fetched from the server (flutter desktop app)

Tags: flutter, websocket

When I fetch the data from the server, I display it on the screen but when I change the data in the server and I press the refresh button, it doesn't update unless I restart the server.

I think the problem is with the server because I tried Postman and made a get request and it returns the same data.

Here is the server code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final server = await HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 5000);
  print('Socket server running on port ${server.port}');

  server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
    if (request.uri.path == '/data') {
      // Call the function to get the voltage and current data
      final jsonData = json.encode(getVoltageCurrentData());
      request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.json; // Add this line
      request.response.write(jsonData);
      request.response.close();
    } else if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)) {
      WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((socket) {
        print('Client connected');

        final interval = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
          // Convert voltageCurrentData to JSON-encoded string before sending
          final jsonData = json.encode(getVoltageCurrentData());
          socket.add(jsonData);
        });

        socket.done.then((_) {
          print('Client disconnected');
          interval.cancel();
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('Error during WebSocket upgrade: $error');
      });
    } else {
      // Handle regular HTTP requests if needed
      request.response.write('WebSocket connection required.');
      //request.response.close();
    }
  });
}

// Function to get voltage and current data
List<Map<String, String>> getVoltageCurrentData() {
  return [
    {'voltage': '120V', 'current': '5A'},
    {'voltage': '110V', 'current': '4A'},
    {'voltage': '95V', 'current': '3A'},
    {'voltage': '100V', 'current': '3A'},
  ];
}
```

And the client code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: VoltageCurrentScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class VoltageCurrentScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VoltageCurrentScreenState createState() => _VoltageCurrentScreenState();
}

class _VoltageCurrentScreenState extends State<VoltageCurrentScreen> {
  WebSocketChannel? channel;

  late List<Map<String, String>> voltageCurrentDataList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    voltageCurrentDataList = [];
    connectToServer();
  }

  void connectToServer() {
    channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse('ws://127.0.0.1:5000'),
    );

    channel?.stream.listen((data) {
      // Decode the JSON data received from the server
      List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(data);
      setState(() {
        // Convert the list of dynamic maps to List<Map<String, String>>
        voltageCurrentDataList =
            jsonData.map((e) => Map<String, String>.from(e)).toList();
      });
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('Error in WebSocket connection: $error');
      channel?.sink.close(); // Close the WebSocket channel on error
    }, onDone: () {
      print('WebSocket connection closed.');
      channel?.sink.close(); // Close the WebSocket channel when done
    });
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        voltageCurrentDataList =
            jsonData.map((e) => Map<String, String>.from(e)).toList();
      });
    } else {
      print('Failed to fetch data from the server.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Voltage & Current Data'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Handle the refresh action here
              fetchData();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(label: Text('Voltage')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('Current')),
            ],
            rows: voltageCurrentDataList.map((data) {
              return DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(data['voltage'] ?? '')),
                DataCell(Text(data['current'] ?? '')),
              ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the data fetched from the server to be updated when I press the refresh button.